# How do I identify rows with empty / undefined enum values in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, enums, null

Suppose I have a Postgres database with a simple table called "test':

```
id
--
1
2
3
```

and an enum definition:

```
CREATE TYPE MyEnum AS ENUM ('UNKNOWN', 'TEST')
```

Now, I can add an enum-valued column to my table:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN my_enum MyEnum;
UPDATE test SET my_enum = 'UNKNOWN'::MyEnum WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE test SET my_enum = 'TEST'::MyEnum WHERE id = 2;
```

And the result is:

```
> SELECT * FROM test;
id  | my_enum
----|--------
1   | UNKNOWN
2   | TEST
3   |
```

What value does my_enum have in row 3? Is there a way to express it? I've tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE my_enum != ''::MyEnum` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE my_enum = null::MyEnum` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE my_enum != ALL(enum_range(null::MyEnum))`. In the first case, I get an error ("invalid input value for enum myenum: """). In the other two, I just get "count: 0".

There seems to be no way to express the value of my_enum in row 3 in Postgres :(. How can I filter only those rows which have my_enum set?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE my_enum IS NOT NULL

Comment: I think Alex means `SELECT * FROM test WHERE my_enum IS NULL`

Answer (score 3):

AlexM answered my question. The code I was looking for is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE my_enum IS NOT NULL
```

My mistake in testing `my_enum = null::MyEnum` was thinking that `null = null` would be true. The [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html) says:

> Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not "equal to" NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.)

I was also tripped up (in testing `my_enum != ALL(enum_range(null::MyEnum))`) by the behavior that

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not true or false, when either input is null. ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html))

Comment: What I needed was `WHERE my_field_a IS DISTINCT FROM my_field_b` (when one of the two could be `NULL`)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between null and an empty string.
NULL is the absence of value.

Use this command so you don't get confused with nulls and empty strings.

`\pset null [null]`