# Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, flask

I am facing a problem when passing JSON from flask to JavaScript :(

The error shows `TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable`. I think it is because of the datatype, but I have use `data_1 = data_1.to_dict('records')`  in my `flask_app.py` file, which makes the data type looks like:

```
[{'Station': 'Taipei', 'Code': 900, 'GateIn': 8442}, 
{'Station': 'Tainan', 'Code': 910, 'GateIn': 1394}, 
{'Station': 'Taichung', 'Code': 920, 'GateIn': 2770}........
]
```

I think this is a correct type of JSON if I want to pass it to Javascript. Here are my python, html, and JS file, can anyone give me some guidance?

**flask_app.py**

```
@app.route("/")
def home(): 
   engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost:5394/station_detail')

   df = pd.read_sql(
       sql = "select * from station;",
       con = engine)

   data_1 = df[['name_c','stationcode','gatein']]
   data_1.columns = ['Station','Code','GateIn']
   data_1 = data_1.to_dict('records') 


   return render_template('/html_template/hello.html', geodata = data_1)

app.run()
```

In my html file, I call my own javascript file (barchart.js):

**HTML:**

```html
<script src = "{{url_for('static',filename='javascript/barchart.js')}}"></script>

<html>

<div class=”canvas”> </div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"  role="img">
</canvas>

</html>

<script>
    var data_1 = JSON.parse('{{ geodata | tojson | safe}}');
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = barchart(data_1,ctx);
    console.log(data_1)

</script>
```

**barchart.js**

```js
function barchart(data, ctx) {
    
    var GateInData = data.map(function (d) {
        return +d.GateIn;
    });

    var stationLabels = data.map(function (d) {
        return d.Station;
    });
    
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: bar,

    data: {
        labels: stationLabels,
        datasets: [{
                data: GateInData,}]},


    options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true}}]}}});
    return chart
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message basically means you have something like

```
[{'Station': 'Taipei', 'Code': 900, 'GateIn': 8442}, 
{'Station': 'Tainan', 'Code': 910, 'GateIn': nothing}, ...
```

and `nothing` is a variable, but it not defined. You need to track down the source of this error and handle it somehow -- guard against having this happen in the first place, or define the variable you thought you had already defined, or remove values which can't be serialized.

(The error message looks like it comes from Python, but eventually the data comes from Postgres. Probably you have something in your database which gets imported as `Undefined` by the SQL driver. Probably see also [How do I identify rows with empty / undefined enum values in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060806/how-do-i-identify-rows-with-empty-undefined-enum-values-in-postgres))